# HttpWebrequest fails with yande.re (and IE and curl)["The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."]

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest

I'm trying programmatically download a page from site **yande.re** using C# HttpWebRequest. It gives exception "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
I had already tried different combinations for
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`
and nothing of those helped. However everything is OK for any other HTTPS request.

What I had noticed is that I can't open this site in InternetExplorer 10 and MINGW curl returns "301 Moved Permanently" for it. Same time browsers like Firefox, Opera, Chrome have no problems with it.
My OS is Windows 7.

So I just wonder what's wrong with yande.re? Or is it me? Can anyone check please. How can I programmatically download anything from it (preferably in C#/C++)?

Comment: results: https://github.com/voidtemp/yande.re.grabber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yande.re) the server support TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. TLS 1.3 is not supported by the Microsoft TLS stack in Windows 7. As for TLS 1.2 the server only supports the following cipher suites:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

Based on [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7) these cipher suites are not supported in Windows 7 though (no TLS_ECDHE_RSA_*GCM* cipher suites are supported and no *CHACHA20*). This means any application which use the Windows TLS stack will not work with the server, notably Internet Explorer and C# applications.

> Same time browsers like Firefox, Opera, Chrome have no problems with it.

These browsers don't use the Windows TLS stack but NSS (Firefox) and BoringSSL (Opera, Chrome). Thus the limitation of the Windows TLS stack do not matter.

> How can I programmatically download anything from it (preferably in C#/C++)?

With C++ you could use OpenSSL as TLS stack which does not have these limitations. Python also uses OpenSSL as TLS stack so it should work too.

Comment: Thanks for reply especially for showing how to track the problem down.
But I'll have to search how "to use OpenSSL as TLS stack" in C# and maybe some C++ wrappers as I want to keep my fancy WindowsForms UI.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand what I'm doing. A 5-seconds problem is now taking forever...

Comment: @TempVoid: I think your original question is answered. If you need help with more please ask a new question and also provide the relevant code, your expectations of what it should do and a description of what it does instead.

Comment: In my opinion it's half answered: answer is more about root cause and less about exact solution. I had to use Python as the fastest result approach. But if I had to use C# or C++ by requirements I would probably have broken my head by this time.

Comment: @TempVoid: True, while the reason for your problem is found, the problem itself is still there. But I find that any problems you have using OpenSSL from C# (as seemed to be your new plan) do not really fit into this question and should better be asked in a new question with the exact details of the problem.